# Передать data-title в div

Tags: javascript

```js
$('.btn_text').click(function() {
  let formTitle = $('.btn_text').data('title');
  $('.form-title').html(formTitle);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-title="Привет 1" href="#" class="btn_text">Привет 1</a>
<a data-title="Привет 2" href="#" class="btn_text">Привет 2</a>
<hr>
<div class="form-title"></div>
```

При первом клике название из `data-title` передается как надо и попадает в `div`, но при клике на следующую кнопку (Привет 2), название остается прежним из (Привет 1), не меняется, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var ids = document.getElementById('input-city');
var lis = [...document.querySelectorAll("ul li")];
var linx = [...document.querySelectorAll("ul li a")];

for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
  lis[i].onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ids.innerHTML = this.getAttribute('data-value')
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="input-city"> </div>
<ul id="ul">
  <li data-value="Город 1"><a href="">Город 1</a></li>
  <li data-value="Город 2"><a href="">Город 2</a></li>
  <li data-value="Город 3"><a href="">Город 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ваша ошибка в том, что необходимо вытаскивать атрибут.

```js
$('.btn_text').click(() => {
  const formTitle = $('.btn_text').attr('title');
  $('.form-title').html(formTitle);
});
```

```css
.btn_text {
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding 5px;
  text-align:center;
  user-select: none;
  cursor:pointer;
  background: cadetblue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px grey;
}
.btn_text:active {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-title">
  default
</div>
<hr>
<div class="btn_text" title="Header">
  Header
</div>
```

Текст не меняется(визуально) потому, что вы присваиваете одно и то же значение. Вот пример с новыми значениями:

```js
// Возвращает случайное число между min (включительно) и max (не включая max)
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

$('.btn_text').click(() => {
  let formTitle = $('.btn_text').attr('title');
  formTitle += getRandomArbitrary(10,19);
  $('.form-title').html(formTitle);
});
```

```css
.btn_text {
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding 5px;
  text-align:center;
  user-select: none;
  cursor:pointer;
  background: cadetblue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px grey;
}
.btn_text:active {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-title">
  default
</div>
<hr>
<div class="btn_text" title="Header">
  Header
</div>
```

Пример с несколькими элементами (самое простое — добавить пользовательский атрибут):

```js
// Возвращает случайное число между min (включительно) и max (не включая max)
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

$('.btn_text').click(function() {
  let element = $(this);
  let title = $(element).attr('title');
  const id = $(element).attr('data-id');
  title += getRandomArbitrary(10,19);
  $(`.form-title-${id}`).html(title);
});
```

```css
.btn_text {
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding 5px;
  text-align:center;
  user-select: none;
  cursor:pointer;
  background: cadetblue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px grey;
}
.btn_text:active {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-title-1">
  default1
</div>
<div class="btn_text" title="Header" data-id="1">
  Header1
</div>
<hr>
<div class="form-title-2">
  default2
</div>
<div class="btn_text" title="Header" data-id="2">
  Header2
</div>
```

Ваш пример:

```js
$('.btn_text').click(function(evet) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const formTitle = $(this).attr('title');
  $('.form-title').html(formTitle);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a title="Привет 1" href="#" class="btn_text">Привет 1</a>
<br>
<a title="Привет 2" href="#" class="btn_text">Привет 2</a>
<hr>
<div class="form-title"></div>
```

*Вы не правильно брали пользовательский атрибут, который вам и не нужно инициализировать. У тега `<a>` есть свой атрибут `title`*.

> Функция **getRandomArbitrary()** взята с [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).

Comment: Проблема остается, 1 раз передает, а при клике на другую кнопку текст не меняется

Comment: ладно, видно я не правильно пояснил задачу, не выходит ее решить , сейчас вопрос изменю с примером сразу

Comment: Изменил вопрос, сразу с примером, что есть у меня

Comment: нет, в input проблем нету как передать, там все просто, но тут стоит другая задача

Comment: блин..точно, спасибо большое, работает+